# I have problem when I pass the data using ajax to controller

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I have a problem with passing the data using ajax to the controller. the delete is the only one work good but the other functions seem like does not get the data from the controller or does not pass the data to the controller.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function($){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $('#addNewBook').click(function () {
       $('#addEditBookForm').trigger("reset");
       $('#ajaxBookModel').html("Add product Category");
       $('#ajax-book-model').modal('show');
    });
 
    $('body').on('click', '.edit', function () {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
         console.log(id);
        // ajax
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "{{ route('admin.edit-productCategory') }}",
            data: { id:id },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(res){
              $('#ajaxBookModel').html("Edit product Category");
              $('#ajax-book-model').modal('show');
              $('#id').val(res.id);
              $('#productCategory').val(res.productCategory);
             

           }
              
        });
          alert(id);
          alert(productCategory);

    });
   
      
    });

</script>
```

Routes:

```
 Route::post('edit-productCategory', [ProductCategoryController::class, 'edit'])->name('admin.edit-productCategory');
```

Controller:

```
public function edit(Request $request)
    {   
        $where = array('id' => $request->id);
        $productCategory  = ProductCategory::where($where)->first();
        return response()->json($productCategory);
        dd($productCategory);
    }
```

Comment: First of all, your `dd()`will never be reached, because the return statement is placed above it. Then, have you tried to `console.log(res)`. As far as i know you need `res.data.id` and `res.data.productCategory`. I would also use `return response()->json(compact('productCategory'));`

Comment: @GertB  I did what you said but the output now is [object Object]

Comment: Because `res.data.productCategory` is an object...  so `res.data.productCategory.id` will output the id

Comment: First of all, you need to write `dd($request->all())` on your first line of the controller method. It will die and dump you the values as key-value pair what has already received your controller method from the front-end part. If you see the value then write your business logic , query etc. After that, return a json response and check from your browser's `network` tab. Sometimes, you will see [object Object]. On that scenario, just write `console.log(JSON.stringify(variable))` and see the value on your console tab. It will help you to debug very well.

Comment: Please `dd($request->all());` in top of function in your controller and share what it return

Answer (score 0):

I am putting `dd` in your controller function before return to ajax:
And I also assume that the `$request->id` have value:

```
public function edit(Request $request)
{   
    $productCategory  = ProductCategory::where('id', $request->id)->first();

    // Remove this dd function after you confirm that your data is shoing;
    dd($productCategory);

    return response()->json($productCategory);
    
}
```

Comment: did not work when I click the edit button it should show a modal for editing but after doing what you said nothing happened and the modal did not show. thank you for your help anyway